# NoSuchElementException throws when try to find out element by x-path

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If i write code in one main class file, it works s well, but when i write code with different class and with method calling, this error is accrued.

Stack trace :

> Time out after 10 seconds {"Unable to locate element:{\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]\"}"}

Code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]")));

var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]"));
admi.Click();
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div class="item-content"style="paddingright:10px; padding-top: 5px">
                  <div class="item-media">
                       <i style="font-size:20px"class="iconProfile2"></i>
                   </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <span class="title"> Profile </span>
                         <i class="icon-arrow" style="margin-top: 3px">
                          </i>
                   </div>
         </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div class="item-content" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 5px">
                                <div class="item-media">
                                    <i style="font-size:20px" class="icon-Profile2"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="title"> Profile </span><i class="icon-arrow" style="margin-top: 3px"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>

Comment: Please incorporate that `HTML` code into your question! Preferably nicely formatted ;-)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are give wrong XPath or 
try following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]")));
var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='item-content'])[position()=3]"));
admi.Click();
```

Install addon of FirePath in Firefox browser and use with Firebug.
and get exact firepath of element and then perform click event.
please check attached image for fire path.[FirePath use example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQj0t.png)
//check image

Comment: I think there is issue in XPath. Download FirePath and use with FireBug in Firefox browser and get exact path of element then. I hope click it will work.

Comment: //*[@id="sidebar"]/div/div[1]/div/nav/ul/li[3]/a/div/div[2]/span    i have tried this laso, which is from firebug

Comment: Check i have attache image for the example of firepath.

Comment: If your problem doesn't resolved yet. then talk me on Skype my id: chmusman5. But I'll be available after 9:00 PST. You can send request for further communication. Thanks.

Comment: Your class name in your code and html is different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `position()=3` is but your xpath is wrong. To get the `<div>` with `item-content` class use

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='item-content']"));
```

Or

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("item-content"));
```

Or using the wait

```
var admi = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("item-content")));
```

`wait.Until` returns the `WebElement` it was waiting for.

> Edit

To select element by position in list use

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='item-content'][3]"));
```

Or put all of them in `List` and choose by index

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("item-content")); // note the spelling of FindElements
elements[2].Click();
```

Comment: item-content is the class which is used in more than 1 <li>.. that why the position is given.

Comment: i have put                    IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("item-content"));
elements[2].Click();

Comment: and it gave  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @disha The index I gave is based on your `position()=3`. I don't know how many items you really have.

Comment: @disha Are they inside `iframe`?

Comment: @disha Check if there is an `iframe` anywhere in the html, not just in the html for the element you want to click.